# Poetry fails to install tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-poetry

I've got a poetry project. My environment is Conda 22.9.0 on a windows machine with poetry version 1.2.2:

This is my pyproject.toml file:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "myproject"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
# REVIEW DEPENDENCIES
python = ">=3.7,<3.11"
numpy = "*"
tensorflow = "^2.8"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry>=0.12"]
build-backend = "poetry.masonry.api"

[tool.poetry.scripts]
start = "myproject.main:start"
```

The myproject\main.py module contains:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def start():
    if tf.test.is_gpu_available():
        print("TensorFlow is using a GPU.")
    else:
        print("TensorFlow is NOT using a GPU.")
```

If I do `poetry install`, it seems to work fine:

```
Creating virtualenv myproject in D:\Projects\myproject\dev\myproject-series-forecast\.venv
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies...

Writing lock file

Package operations: 41 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

• Installing certifi (2022.12.7)
• Installing charset-normalizer (2.1.1)
• Installing idna (3.4)
• Installing pyasn1 (0.4.8)
• Installing urllib3 (1.26.13)
• Installing cachetools (5.2.0)
• Installing oauthlib (3.2.2)
• Installing rsa (4.9)
• Installing six (1.16.0)
• Installing zipp (3.11.0)
• Installing requests (2.28.1)
• Installing pyasn1-modules (0.2.8)
• Installing google-auth (2.15.0)
• Installing importlib-metadata (5.2.0)
• Installing requests-oauthlib (1.3.1)
• Installing markupsafe (2.1.1)
• Installing absl-py (1.3.0)
• Installing grpcio (1.51.1)
• Installing numpy (1.21.6)
• Installing tensorboard-data-server (0.6.1)
• Installing markdown (3.4.1)
• Installing tensorboard-plugin-wit (1.8.1)
• Installing protobuf (3.19.6)
• Installing werkzeug (2.2.2)
• Installing google-auth-oauthlib (0.4.6)
• Installing astunparse (1.6.3)
• Installing flatbuffers (22.12.6)
• Installing gast (0.4.0)
• Installing google-pasta (0.2.0)
• Installing h5py (3.7.0)
• Installing keras (2.11.0)
• Installing tensorflow-estimator (2.11.0)
• Installing packaging (22.0)
• Installing opt-einsum (3.3.0)
• Installing libclang (14.0.6)
• Installing tensorboard (2.11.0)
• Installing tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem (0.29.0)
• Installing termcolor (2.1.1)
• Installing typing-extensions (4.4.0)
• Installing wrapt (1.14.1)
• Installing tensorflow (2.11.0)

Installing the current project: myproject (0.1.0)
```

But when executing `poetry run start` I got error in import

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "D:\Projects\myproject\dev\myproject-series-forecast\myproject\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Comment: I noticed that comparing to a different virtual environment I have in my Anaconda installation, the ./venv/Libs/site-pacakges folder under the poetry project didn't contain a /tensorflow subfolder (despite the message in `poetry install` stating that tensorflow was successfully installed). To solve this, I had to manually install with `pip install tensorflow==2.11.0 --force-reinstall` after entering the virtual env with `poetry shell`. Then, the module not found error disappears.

Answer (score 10):

For anyone dealing with the error message:

`Unable to find installation candidates for tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem (0.32.0)`

It's because of the version not compatible with the tensorflow version you're trying to install (see compatibility [here](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem/)). For example, if you're trying to install tensorflow 2.10.*, you need to explicitly define the appropriate version of tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem in the .toml file (i.e., `tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem = "0.27.0"`).

Then proceed with downloading tensorflow (i.e., `poetry add tensorflow@~2.10`)

Comment: Table of version compatibility is at https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem/

Answer (score 5):

I can confirm that for TF 2.11 this indeed an issue.
Can't give you a definite answer as to why this no longer works, but it seems [to be metadata related](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/58674#issuecomment-1456585828).
Pip has no issues installing it, as already mentioned in the comments.

2.10 still works in poetry, not that that helps.

Comment: Actually on my Mac M2 not even 2.10 works. 2.11 gives " Unable to find installation candidates for tensorflow (2.11.1)", 2.10 gives "Unable to find installation candidates for tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem (0.32.0)" ... what a nightmare

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me by changing [python = ">=3.7,<3.11"] to [python = ">=3.8,<3.12"]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

For me there was a conflict when installing scikit-learn together with tensorflow. I followed the tip of @Neeraj Sharma .

**before code**

```py
[tool.poetry]
name = "my-project"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Your Name <you@example.com>"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
jupyter = "^1.0.0"
scikit-learn = "1.2.2"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

**output**

```bash
➜ poetry install
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (2.5s)

The current project's Python requirement (>=3.10,<4.0) is not compatible with some of the required packages Python requirement:
  - tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem requires Python >=3.7, <3.11, so it will not be satisfied for Python >=3.11,<4.0

Because my-project depends on tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem (0.27.0) which requires Python >=3.7, <3.11, version solving failed.

  • Check your dependencies Python requirement: The Python requirement can be specified via the `python` or `markers` properties
    
    For tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem, a possible solution would be to set the `python` property to ">=3.10,<3.11"

    https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#python-restricted-dependencies,
    https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#using-environment-markers
```

I had to look at the poetry documentation because the example is complicated to understand.

[Docs Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/)
[Docs PEP 508](https://peps.python.org/pep-0508/#environment-markers)

This problem we had, because it was solved with this specification of PEP 508. I didn't know it either, it ended up being a new learning experience. I recommend reading.

**Solution**

In [tool.poetry.dependencies] you will add the version marker, I used the one from the output. I put a slightly older version of latest. Then I added the tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem lib specifying its version. There may be a better way to solve this, but I'm still new to poetry. It was the best solution.

[tool.poetry.dependencies]

```py
[tool.poetry]
name = "udemy-tensorflow-developer-certificate-in-2023-zero-to-mastery"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Your Name <you@example.com>"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8,<3.11"
jupyter = "^1.0.0"
scikit-learn = "1.2.2"
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem = { version = "0.27.0"}
tensorflow = "2.12.0"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

After that I managed to install tensorflow together with scikit-learn.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using MBP M1 for which there is apparently no prebuilt binaries included by the default `tensorflow` package. Instead as suggested here https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/6079#issuecomment-1250119572 I had to install specific `tensorflow-macos` package.

Quite silly as anybody now installing the project who does not have macOS would install the wrong version. So I probably have to add some kind of hacky configuration in the `pyproject.toml` file.

Answer (score 0):

For MBP M1 and later users, as @TeemuK mentioned, there are no tensorflow binaries provided. I had to specifically update `.toml` file and run `poetry install`. To resolve dependency issues, you can run `poetry lock --no-update`.
This answer assumes you have poetry installed globally and already initialized.

`Tree command output`:
[Tree folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AeA9.png)

## pyproject.toml file:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "pack"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["JordanTheDodger <jordanthedodger@gmail.com>"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.7,<3.12"
ipykernel = {"version"="^6.29.0","python"=">=3.8,<3.12"}
pandas = {"version"="^2.1.4","python"=">=3.9,<3.12"}
matplotlib = {"version"="^3.8.2","python"=">=3.9,<3.12"}
tensorflow-macos = {"version"="2.10.0","python"=">=3.9,<3.12"}

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

**Disclaimer**: *I am using poetry virtual env in .ipnyb file. Please ignore `ipykernel` package. Also, `tesnorflow-macos v2.10` is stable then future versions and fit for most production env*

Answer (score 0):

### Poetry Solution to tensorflow version conflict

I ran into a similar problem with my poetry-based project. Here is how I fixed it.

Its a version conflict wioth tensorflow I fixed by adding these two lines to your pyproject.toml to change your python version and the tensorflow dependency causing the issue.

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.10, <3.11"
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem = "0.27.0"
```

Then run

```
poetry lock --no-update
```

and

```
poetry install
```

to see if your dependency issues are resolved.

---

This solution is based on the poetry log:

> Because your_project depends on tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem (0.27.0)
> which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed. poetry lock
> --no-update Resolving dependencies... (0.4s)
>
> The current project's supported Python range (>=3.10,<4.0) is not
> compatible with some of the required packages Python requirement:
>
> - tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem requires Python >=3.7, <3.11, so it will not be satisfied for Python >=3.11,<4.0
>
> Because ml depends on tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem (0.27.0) which
> requires Python >=3.7, <3.11, version solving failed.